# Разместить сайт за рубежом и в России

Tags: хостинг, dns, веб-сайт

Задумался в связи с последними событиями о том, как разместить сайт на зарубежном хостинге, а на случай если включится блокировка интернета и суверенный интернет будет доступен - чтобы на русском хостинге была копия сайта. Как такое провернуть?

Предположим для простоты, что сайт - набор статических страниц, есть сервер А с IP=100.200.1.2 который находится у хостера hetzner в Германии и есть сервер Б с IP=200.1.2.3 который находится у хостера reg.ru в России. Знаю, что крупные компании держат самостоятельно DNS-сервера и если поставить на них модифицированный dns-сервер (какой?) который пропатчен так, что для IP-адресов из России будет резолвить А-запись домена в сервер Б, а для всего остального мира - в IP-адрес сервера А.

Не знаю, насколько это сложно поднять самому, может есть готовые сервисы?

Comment: https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01149  https://www.rootusers.com/loading-different-website-content-based-on-country-with-geodns/